# UIRefreshControl hides behind navigation bar.

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

So I have a `UIRefreshControl` inside of my table view controller. I did all the necessary steps to allocate etc. It works just great. My problem is positioning. Is there a way to bump the y coordinate down a bit so the refresh control is not hiding behind the nav bar? Note: I had to add the the refresh control to my tableview like so: `[self.categoryList addSubview:self.refreshControl];` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured out my problem. It was rather silly, I had this inside my code:

```
if([[UIDevice currentDevice].systemVersion floatValue]>=7.0)
    [self.categoryList setFrame:CGRectMake(0, -35, 320,self.categoryList.frame.size.height+35)];
```